What is the adverb in these sentences "I love you too" and "I too love you"?
I love you too and I too love you
If the adverb is too, then what it does modify. Either it modifies the pronouns I and you respectively or the verb love?

'Too' certainly doesn't necessarily directly qualify the verb, as a prototypical adverb does:

I love you dearly / I dearly love you.

Gast [@ De Gruyter] classes 'also', and this sense of 'too', as additive particles.
Druskat, in The distribution of also and too, examines POS-tagging, commenting:

The two preceding studies concerned with the distribution of also
and too, Fjelkestam-Nilsson (1983) and Gast (2006), classify them
differently. While Fjelkestam-Nilsson chooses a term relative to their
grammatical function – ‘additive adverbials’ – and follows Quirk &
Greenbaum (1973) in sub-classifying them as ‘additive focusing
adjuncts’, Gast classifies them on the level of lexical category and
adopts a terminology that accounts for any difficulties in assigning
also and too to any one strict grammatical function by using the
rather open term ‘additive particles’.

...............

(2) I too love you

means                                                           A (,B, C ...) love you, and so do I.

(1) I love you too

is polysemous, and can mean                  (a) A (,B, C ...) love/s you, and so do I.
                                                                        (b) [I love A, B, and C ...] and you.
                                                                        (c) [You love me, and] I you.
                                                                        (d) [As well as being your friend,] I love you.
                                                                        (e) [As well as everything I've just stated,] I love you.
In speech, primary and secondary stress would probably be:

1(a)                                                             I love you too.

1(b)                                                             I love you too.

1(c)                                                             I love you too.

1(d)                                                             I love you too.

1(e)                                                             I love you too.


which, together with context, helps disambiguate.

"too" can sometimes be understood to modify not a single word but the entire assertion.
too can express  reciprocity:

(You have said that you love me). I love you too.

There the entire assertion "I love you" is being framed or cast by too as reciprocal.
too can express the notion of (in) addition:

Another loves you. I too love you.
Another loves you. I love you too.

In the former, there is syntactic emphasis on I by virtue of the placement of too, drawing attention to I. And in the latter there would probably be a vocal tonal emphasis on I when speaking .

I love another.  I love you too.

you also are someone I love.  There would probably be a vocal emphasis on you and on too when speaking, in metrical terms, a spondee. I love YOU TOO.

I like the red one. I like the blue one too.  I like them both.  Vocal emphasis on blue.


That means "too", as an adverb, qualifies those sentences wholly. Am I right?
